# What if passport expires after I -130 is filed and before Consular processing starts?

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

I am filing for my parent's green card. I am preparing to file for I-130 as of today which is February 2020. Now, I also realized that their passport is expiring in April of 2021, which "may" expire before their consular filing starts.

Let me ask some specific questions around this situation:

1. What happens if their passport actually expires before consular processing starts. Now, the passport information on I-130 is no longer valid because they have a new passport.
2. Is it better/safer for me to just have their passport renewed right now and then file for their I-130 to completely avoid this situation?

Comment: I assume you mean 'April 2020' and not 2021?

Comment: @MarkJohnson, no it is actually 2021. I am worried because consular processing after I file for I-130 may take more than a year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passport number you put on the I-130 doesn't really matter. In fact, they are not required to have a passport to be petitioned. What matters is the passport they present then they actually apply for the immigrant visa.